# Plot3D and NMinimize do not work correctly?

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

See my code:

```
ref = Rasterize[Graphics3D[Sphere[]], ImageResolution -> 16, 
Background -> LightYellow]
Model[{x_, y_}] := 
Rasterize[Graphics3D[Sphere[], ViewPoint -> {x, y, 1}], 
ImageResolution -> 16, Background -> LightYellow]
CostFunction[{x_, y_}] := 
Total[Flatten[ImageData[ImageSubtract[ref, Model[{x, y}]]]]]
 Plot3D[CostFunction[{x, y}], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3}].// My problem is here?????
```

But When I use

```
list = ParallelTable[{x, y, CostFunction[{x, y}]}, {x, -10, 
10}, {y, -10, 10}];
list = ParallelTable[{x, y, CostFunction[{x, y}]}, {x, -10, 
10}, {y, -10, 10}];
```

I get the function graphics! What is the problem?

In the other hand:

I want to minimize the cost function using `NMinimize[]`

```
NMinimize[CostFunction[{x, y}], {x, y}]
{22083.2,{x->0,y->0}}
```

But When I calculate

```
CostFunction[{0,0}]
```

I obtain 8758.65? What is the issue please?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to local situation and needs of its poster, and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the you `CostFunction` which is extremely slow because in each call it has to render a graphics, rasterize it and compute the difference of the two images. You can see that `Plot3D` basically works by restricting the number of points if computes. With 10 plot points, which results in 10x10 values to compute, the graphic needs about 20 seconds here

```
Plot3D[CostFunction[{x, y}], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In default mode, `Plot3D` will divide each interval further if the surface is *too rough**. I have suppressed that by setting `MaxRecursion` to 0.

## Update

About your second question. I cannot reproduce your behavior, because when I compute on my machine

```
NMinimize[CostFunction[{x, y}], {x, y}]
```

I obtain

```
{6493.44, {x -> 0.500146, y -> -0.500021}}
```

When I calculate `CostFunction[{.5, -.5}]` then I get the same value.

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro Core i7 and 8G of RAM and it takes 70s??? What is the characteristic of your computer? please!

Comment: @phdstudent Intel Core i7 Extreme, 32 GB RAM. I'm on Linux here, which might make (in this special case) a difference too.

Comment: And What about the NMinimize Function?

Comment: @phdstudent I get a position of about `{0.5,-0.5}` where `CostFunction` has the exact same value as pointed out by `NMinimize`.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand you.

Comment: @phdstudent See my update.

Comment: I use also FindMinimum[CostFunction[{x, y}], {{x, 0}, {y, 0}}, 
 Gradient :> {"FiniteDifference"}] but I get this error  FindMinimum::fmgz: Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero. The result returned may not be a minimum; it may be a maximum or a saddle point

Comment: Ok! I see! thanks!! That is amazing!

Comment: Could you please try me the FindMinimum[] function on your computer?

Comment: @phdstudent `FindMinimum` gives the same error message you posted.

Comment: Ok, thanks for cooperation!

Comment: Did you change a little beat in my code when you calculate NMinimize[CostFunction[{x, y}], {x, y}] because I do not think that the error is because of the machine processor or Ram!! It is amazing?